# proper NSURL request encoding

Tags: iphone, ipad, http, encoding, character-encoding

I need to encode the body of my POST request but I don´t know which one to use. 
I´m having a trouble with changing ´(´ into %28. 
I was using so far NSUTF8StringEncoding, NSISOLatin1StringEncoding, NSISOLatin2StringEncoding. Non of them works.

The name of the parameter I have to send is:

```
monitoring_report[monitoring_report_time(1i)]=
```

which sould be transformed to:

```
monitoring_report%5monitoring_report_time%281i%29%5D=
```

and what I get is:

```
monitoring_report%5Bmonitoring_report_time(1i)%5D=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Core Foundation function `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` which has a `legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped` parameter. Parenthesis in URLs are legal which is why they're not escaped by default.

Example:

```
NSString *input = @"monitoring_report[monitoring_report_time(1i)]=";
NSString *output = [(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)input, NULL, CFSTR("()"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease];
NSLog(@"%@", output); // monitoring_report%5Bmonitoring_report_time%281i%29%5D=
```